# IPv6 record will not take for rDNS

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, ipv6, reverse-dns

I added the following to named.conf

```
zone "3IP6.A.B.C.ip6.arpa" {
type master;
file "3IP6.A.B.C.ip6.arpa";
allow-update { none; };
};
```

I then created my dns zone record called 3IP6.A.B.C.ip6.arpa which contains:

```
; IPV6/128
$TTL 1h ; Default TTL
@ IN SOA rdnsmain.domain.com noc.domain.com (
2014121001 ; serial
1h ; slave refresh interval
15m ; slave retry interval
1w ; slave copy expire time
1h ; NXDOMAIN cache time
)
@ IN NS rdnsmain.domain.com
; IPv6 PTR entries
3IP6.A.B.C.ip6.arpa. IN PTR my.domainnet.
```

On a restart I get the following:

```
Error in named configuration:
zone 3IP6.A.B.C.ip6.arpa/IN: NS 'rdnsmain.domain.com.3IP6.A.B.C.ip6.arpa' has no address records (A or AAAA)
zone 3IP6.A.B.C.ip6.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/3IP6.A.B.C.ip6.arpa/IN: bad zone
zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
```

Any ideas what the errors are? This is my first time working with IPv6 and rDNS on my own.

Comment: Your attempt at anonymization of your data is almost certainly hiding the error in this case.  But one of the errors related to your NS record is that you are **missing the trailing period**, see `'rdnsmain.domain.com.3IP6.A.B.C.ip6.arpa' has no address records`

Answer (score 2):

Actually that *is* the error. You forgot the trailing period on your NS record.